# Can't create tag synonym

Tags: feature-request, tag-synonyms, privileges

I recently reached a reputation which enables me to create tag synonyms.
I tried to prepose a tag synonym for [anacrusis](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anacrusis) with [pickup-measure](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pickup-measure), which I assume would be uncontroversial.

Over a year ago, I asked [a question](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/92425/anacruses-bar-lines-and-line-breaks) on this topic that was well received (+9 votes).  But, as I haven't answered any questions in either of these tags, my answer score is still 0.
It's a relatively unpopular topic, so gaining the required answer score is unlikely to happen anytime soon.

So I can't prepose the synonym.

---

I don't really understand why I'm still not allowed to do this;
*Wouldn't it be beneficial if question scores could be added into the count for allowing tag synonym proposals?*

Comment: This would be a Meta.SE topic, but it looks like there is already some support for (and several discusses related to) changing the tag-synonym situation (see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103211/can-we-allow-7-5k-users-to-suggest-tag-synonyms-without-a-score-of-5-in-the-tag), for example, although that suggestion is a bit different than yours). Let me know if you'd like me to create it; it seems like a worthwhile synonym!

Comment: @Richard  
Ah yes, I think you are right it does seem like a duplicate/similar question to that link. I see that the Meta Stack Exchange community seems to support the idea of lowering the threshold for tag synonym proposals, but it's "status-declined" for some reason.

If you can create the synonym proposal for that that would be great, thank you.